# A little wish to you

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Ale. Hope this helps.

Answer is one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be

> HEALTH
>
>  H (from Hope), EAL (anagram of ALE), T (from This), H (from Helps)

Comment: Correct. And regards to the title, the wish is "Drink (implied by *ale*) to your *health*" :)